# get an image and parse it as binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curb

I'm using curb to get an image like so :

```
curl = Curl::Easy.new("http://www.myimage.com/path/to/my.jpg")
curl.perform
```

Now I need to save the returned `curl.body_str` into the database, which is expecting type `binary`. The `body_str` is returned as a string, so how can I massage it such that it can be save into the database as binary?

Comment: cur.body_str.unpack(*B) that will convert your string to the binary

Comment: thanks for the quick response. For future reference, you can go on to store it in the db by serializing the model attribute.